# Formatting Facet/Multi-View Labels in vega-lite

Tags: vega, vega-lite

Was wondering if there was a way to specify formatting for the Labels of the individual cells in a facet flow.

For example, for something like https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/trellis_barley.html

Can I edit the label font sizes and anchors/baselines for the little labels that say "Grand Rapid Falls", "Duluth", etc.?

The closest thing I've been able to do is globally edit all the labels using a global `config`, but that also affects other labels like "Trebi", "wisconson No. 38", etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels and titles for facets (including `facet`, `row`, and `column` encodings) are controlled by the `"header"` property.

For example you could use something like this in the chart you linked to ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-o7PD63DIRjUfB6U0VD56BkAJhdjmQSh5G2oIY0BuGB2yyYgWagwwpYicltgkj92cgeFsJUtCw2eRLWcgPLErFQLz0kdd2agigMvpNkG4hEtOkiUzUObzBd85Mpzo7pZQ6BWmc7Bq8eBsAGFuGIFpbqEY43XS2ubAAxZR4ADKjAAXrocNI2XPO2XmDYAILxxC73xxgvP0sYnYYwtx3AxLSMf8UxfIDjHPXZrzvNsn2gwCqmMT8kB-LtKh7SBULAJ1oJjUtfmXUt0GofdhD2IdSghFQAPHGcpwnI99Are8oAAR1YKY1yBRgqHYyAEDyLjTTvNE9DTMRXiI7MSPrew+1zFioDBdxsnsLky04qs5R2WtdO7XsoBEMilINRtsNNNT80tWxkCsMc9MrXwlF5IyxGdDQiKdIA))

```
  "encoding": {
    "facet": {
      ...
      "header": {
        "titleColor": "green",
        "titleFontSize": 40,
        "titleAnchor": "end",
        "labelColor": "red",
        "labelFontSize": 20,
        "labelAnchor": "start"
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

More information on available label and title configurations can be found in the Vega-Lite [Header documentation](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/header.html).